# Primitive Element Theorem

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the primtive element theorem, as written in Milne's [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf).

It is not emphasized there where the assumption that $\beta$ is separable over $F$ is used in the following lemma.

> 1. Is it really only used to show that $k=1$? (see the proof for definition of $k$)
> 2. Is it true that if the assumption that $\beta$ is separable is dropped, then $p$ must divide $k$ and therefore this proof always fails?

**Lemma:** Let $F$ be an infinite field. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be algebraic over $F$ and assume that $\beta$ is separable over $F$. Then, there is $c\in F$ such that $F[\alpha,\beta]=F[\alpha+c\beta]$
**Proof:** Let $f,g\in F[X]$ be the minimal polynomials of $\alpha,\beta$ respectively. Let $L$ be the splitting field over $F[\alpha,\beta]$ of the polynomial $fg$. Let $\alpha=\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dotsc,\alpha_s$ be the roots of $f$ in $L$ and let $\beta=\beta_1,\beta_2,\dotsc,\beta_t$ be the roots of $g$ in $L$. Consider the equations $\alpha_i+c\beta_j=\alpha+c\beta$ for every $i,j$ with $j>1$. Each such equation has exactly one solution. Therefore, since $F$ is infinite, there is an element $c\in F$ which is *not* a solution for each of these equations. We shall see that $F[\alpha,\beta]=F[\alpha+c\beta]$. It is enough to show that $\beta\in F[\alpha+c\beta]$. Consider the polynomials $f((\alpha+c\beta)-cX)$ and $g(X)$. Both of them are elements of $F[\alpha+c\beta][X]$ and therefore, so is their $\gcd$. But the choice of $c$ guarantees that $\beta$ is the only root common to both of them. Therefore, this $\gcd$ is of the form $(X-\beta)^k$ for a certain $k\geq 1$. Therefore, the coefficient of $X^{k-1}$ in the $\gcd$ is $-k\beta$. Therefore, unless $\text{char}F \mid k$, we have shown that $\beta\in F[\alpha+c\beta]$. If $\beta$ is separable over $F$, then $k=1$ and we are good.